# Form inside a panel Datagridview VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I have a form that opens inside a panel. It has a Datagridview in it. What i'm trying to do is when i select a row and click edit i get the current selected row's text inside the edit form. I've previously got this working when using Showdialog. This time i don't want it in a showdialog form.

The code i'm using closes the form with the Datagrid and does actually display the top row fine. But when i select a different row it still shows the top row in the edit form.

Here's the code:

```
Try
        If (CIM.Panel2.Controls.Count > 0) Then
            CIM.Panel2.Controls.RemoveAt(0)
        End If
        Dim F1 As New CIMCLIENTEDIT()
        F1.TopLevel = False
        F1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        CIM.Panel2.Controls.Add(F1)
        F1.Show()
        F1.txtstdid.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
        F1.txtName.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
        F1.txtEmail.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString
        F1.txtNo.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString
        F1.txtAddress.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Text)
    End Try
```

The code is an exact copy of the code that works with a showdialog. Obviously the above code is closing the first form in the panel before opening the edit form, however, it does seem to be getting the top row of the Datagrid just fine.

This works:

```
Try

        CIMCLIENTEDIT.Text = "Edit Details"
        CIMCLIENTEDIT.txtstdid.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
        CIMCLIENTEDIT.txtName.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
        CIMCLIENTEDIT.txtEmail.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
        CIMCLIENTEDIT.txtNo.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString
        CIMCLIENTEDIT.txtAddress.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString
        CIMCLIENTEDIT.ShowDialog()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Text)
    End Try
```

Many Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 1):

I overlooked something very simple.. It appears that i should have been closing the panel afterwards! Makes sense..

```
Try

    Dim F1 As New CIMCLIENTEDIT()
    F1.TopLevel = False
    F1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    CIM.Panel2.Controls.Add(F1)
    F1.Show()
    F1.txtstdid.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
    F1.txtName.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
    F1.txtEmail.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString
    F1.txtNo.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString
    F1.txtAddress.Text = dgvData.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString

    If (CIM.Panel2.Controls.Count > 0) Then
        CIM.Panel2.Controls.RemoveAt(0)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, Me.Text)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

The crucial point is your `dgvData` variable. Please check how and where you are initializing it, and where you are setting the `CurrentRow`property.

Comment: Hi @SQLPolice thanks for your reply. I'm struggling with this! I've added the code that works. I'm trying to not use ShowDialog. I want it as a new form inside the panel. It works for the first row as mentioned.. i'm missing something obvious here!